# Matplotlib and networkx merging Graphs when drawing

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm using [Networkx](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/drawing.html) to visualise some graphs using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def drawgraph(g, filename):
    #plt.figure() I had to comment this line because it gives me an 'alloc: invalid block` error
    nx.draw(g)
    plt.draw() # I added this hoping it might solve the problem (outlined in the text below the code)
    plt.savefig(filename)
   #plt.show() this solves the problem, however it's blocking call and I'm drawing hundreds of graphs
```

Now the problem is that subsequent calls to `drawgraph`, will cause the drawn graphs to be merged with the previous ones e.g: if I call it twice, the first one is drawn correctly but the second picture contains the the first Graph in addition to the second Graph. Putting a `plt.show()` at the end of the function solves the Problem, however it's a blocking call and I can't have that. So how do I solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

So after some looking around I found out the answer, I uncommented the `plt.figure()` line and added a `plt.close()` call at the end:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def drawgraph(g, filename):
    plt.figure()
    nx.draw(g)
    plt.draw() 
    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you plot something and then plot something again, with `matplotlib.pyplot`, both things will appear.  You need to close or clear the figure.

Adding `plt.clf()` to clear the figure will solve the problem.  I don't believe `plt.draw()` does anything for you.